# Using Vaadin Framework with Google App Engine and Firebase using only Java

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, firebase, vaadin

Question:
Can I use the Firebase Java APIs (meant for Android) with Vaadin classes for my Web UI? In the end they're APIS and which client calls them should be inconsequential (unless they're tightly coupled with android APIs)?
otherwise, Can I use Vaadin framework to "inject" java script for Firebase into my UI? (This can get messy very quickly though).

Background:
After multiple tutorials and products I've narrowed down my list to use Vaadin framework for my UX (Priority Java), Firebase (authentication, Security, sync, etc.) and GAE (documentation, articles, support, pricing). Before investing too much effort into this combination, I'd like to know if would work (technically) in the first place?

Comment: Welcome to SO. this is realy more of a recommendation request than a programming question. you may have better luck over at http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks & Good to be here. I still consider it a programming question from a technical feasibility point of view? I mean I don't know if what I am attempting is right in the first place?

Comment: But thanks for your advice. I would try posting it at softwarerecs as well.

Comment: I mean I don't think it's on-topic here at SO. typically we help with specific problems that are being encoutnered. While the "can this be done" aspect of your question could be answered with a yes or no.  The question reads more like you are searching for advice and I cannot decipher from it what an acceptable answer to it would look like from your perspective. Your are certainly free to leave it but I'd check the community page that describes what is on topic to make sure you believe it belongs within a community context: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Thank you for your comment. And apologies since I am very new to the Forum. Please let me know if my question is more specific now. I would otherwise be to remove it form this forum.

Comment: much better good job